# flutter devices command does not show my iPhone in mac

Tags: ios, xcode, android-studio, flutter

`flutter devices` command does not detect my iPhone in the mac terminal.

This command showing my android devices properly but not iOS.

I am running macOS 10.15.1 in MacBook Air and iOS 13.2.2 in iPhone SE (both are the latest version now)

My mac showing my iPhone properly while connected via USB as well as Xcode also showing it.

I don't know why flutter and Android Studio don't detect it.

Comment: Have you followed *all* the steps at https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos?

Comment: I already followed these steps.